# Bash Script to add first 10 numbers i.e 1 to 10 using control statement

Tags: bash, shell

I want to know how can we add the first 10 numbers using bash script. The addition should be done using control statement. Do I need to use Array ? if someone can show me an example then I would very thankful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script in bash:

```
for i in {1..10}; do s=$((s+i)); done; echo $s
```

#### OUTPUT

```
55
```

Comment: instead using a for loop,why not use the mathematical formula n(n+1)/2 which is 10+11/2=55: echo $(((s/2)*(s+1)))

Comment: @Rahul Dravid: Sure that can also be done but it is always not possible to use matematical formula to do some computation and in those cases iterating over the range is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
seq -s + 1 10 | bc -ql
```

This is perhaps a contrived answer, but it does the job..

- -s uses the given argument to separate the output. In this way we can build the output string for bc
- seq takes up to 3 arguments, last, first and last, or first increment and last.

bc is a calulator:

- -q means quiet
- -l means include mathlib -- probably not necessary but won't hurt.

Check out man seq/bc for the juicy details..